# MySQL to Clickhouse DB migration

Tags: clickhouse

For one of our client requirements, I am migrating a database from RDS MySQL to EC2 Clickhouse (CH).

I have created the table structure successfully in CH as in MySQL.

When creating a table view for CH, I am not finding an exact match in Clickhouse for the following MySQL query. Any guidance will be very helpful.

MySQL create view statement:

```
select  
    concat('["', DateTime(Column Name, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'), '", "', 
    cast(truncate(Col name, 20) as char charset utf8), '"]') AS abc 
from tablename
```

I am in need of an equivalent Clickhouse query for this
**-->** retrieving the time part alone from the `DateTime` column is not successful and I need a CH query also for this.

Comment: Please provide the expected query result.

Comment: ["2016-01-01T12:00:00Z", "410.99999999999994000000"] is my expected and needed output

Comment: Show your data and your expected output.

Comment: Expected output is already commented.. Data is in datetime format.. have posted my SQL query also

Answer (score 0):

Use `formatDateTime` and `floor` functions:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    datetime_column DateTime,
    col_name Decimal(34, 22)
) Engine = TinyLog;

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (now(), 491.00000000000000000001999), (toStartOfMonth(now()), 499.98765123212376237836969619468);
    
SELECT formatDateTime(datetime_column, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'), floor(col_name, 20) FROM mytable;

Query id: e325d667-ad06-42dc-894b-a8d1c65fa66c

┌─formatDateTime(datetime_column, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')─┬──────floor(col_name, 20)─┐
│ 2022-10-19T09:14:05Z                            │ 491.00000000000000000001 │
│ 2022-10-01T00:00:00Z                            │ 499.98765123212376237836 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘

2 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```